# When did Euler find his formula for $\zeta(2n)$

Tags: math-history, riemann-zeta

Does anybody know when Euler found his famous formula $$\zeta(2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2\pi)^{2n}B_{2n}}{2(2n)!}?$$

Comment: This might be useful https://goo.gl/NFlx6R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like 1734, according to this article.  But he didn't prove it completely until a few years later.

http://www.math.wvu.edu/~mays/745/Euler%20and%20the%20zeta%20function.pdf